# Determine Click Once Publish Directory

Tags: c#, clickonce

How do I reference the ClickOnce directory to which my application was published?

I've tried ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployement.DataDirectory and Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location but they point to where the application is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is [ActivationUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.activationuri.aspx) what you are looking for:

```
ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri
```

Answer (score 0):

The publish url is stored in the .csproj file:

```
<PublishUrl>[Your path goes here]</PublishUrl>
```

I suspect this isn't much use to you at run-time though.